# Cross platform continuous integration pipeline for C++ / Qt applications

Tags: c++, continuous-integration, cmake, premake

**EDIT 2012.03.02: updated build tool section with some other requirements. Addding premake.**

**EDIT 2012.03.05: updated build tool section. Focused on CMake. Added Ant + CMakeAnt.**

I have a lot of small Visual C++ projects and I want to start using continuous integration for that. A lot of tools are involved in the process. I start reading articles here and there and it is hard for me to see which to tool could integrate nicely with the others. So I am looking for an already tested continuous integration workflow that could respect my needs:

**Current Context**

- C++/Qt applications developed with Visual Studio;
- Less than 1'000 source files;
- Small dev team;
- Small budget;
- Preferably open source/free software;
- Looking for easy to use and simple tools. No need of something heavy and "powerful".
- Finally packages software (installers ready for download) should work for windows and OSX. Linux (most popular distributions) is a plus.

**Tools needed**

- Continuous Integration Server:

  Needs to be Jenkins. I know it and I like it. I could change for another one if it is really needed.
- Source Code Management:

  GIT.
- Documentation Generator:

  Doxygen.
- Build Tool:

  We will need to generate solutions and configurations for all the platforms we need to support. I have been strongly advised to use CMake for that. Ant + CMakeAnt (http://code.google.com/p/cmakeant/) seems to be a nice addition too.
- Unit Testing Framework:

  CPPunit, C++Test, Googletest?
- Installers Builder

  CPack (part of CMake seems great too).
- Hardware:

  Preferably, one single machine with VirtualBox or VMWare. is it only possible? Would it be better to use Linux for such things? Or would a MAC mini be sufficient?

So, has anyone here already built something similar? With which tools exactly?

Thanks for any comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully used CMake/CTest/CPack with Jenkins, there is a CMake builder plugin available.

I found the `ctest --output-on-failure` option to be useful as the output from the test is shown in the Jenkins log on failure.

I use the [Boost.Test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) framework for testing C++, it works fine with ctest, I run it with the `-l all` option to get all the logging output when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to bootstrap the entire process using a bunch of scripts.

Write them in `Perl` or `Python`. There are a million tutorials on how to bootstrap these sorts of processes.

If you're stuck on implementing a specific party of this build-process, ask a specific question about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is maybe not clear but for the moment, I am only trying to see which tools and hardware to use depending on my specific needs. Then, I will try to build it. Testing each one of those tools during 2 days will take forever and will never help me to make an educated choice. That's why I am relying on experienced people here (those who actually used/built one)^^